# How to use image as input in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am working on using a convolutional neural network in a website that I am developing but am unsure how to create an input for an image.

The CNN model was trained in keras and then converted to a tensorflow.js format and is loading without problem. However, when I am trying to use an image as an input with the tf.fromPixels method within tensorflow.js, I am experiencing an issue stating:

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin
>   data, and may not be loaded."

The image itself is locally stored and being shown in the webpage (the entire page is just being run locally at the moment). How would I go about feeding an image into the `tensorflow.js` CNN model? Is there anyways to use a local image through an html `<img/>` tag or does it have to be hosted online? My guess is that the `fromPixels()` method is causing a CORS error but I'm unsure if thats certainly the case and anyways around it.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in that the CORS error is coming from WebGL's fromPixels() method.

There are two ways you can get around it.

First,
You could request permission from the server with a function like

```
function requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url) {
  if ((new URL(url)).origin !== window.location.origin) {
    img.crossOrigin = ""; //this requests permission from the server
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
...
requestCORSIfNotSameOrigin(img, url);
img.src = url;
```

Note that some servers may not grant permission.
[Read more about WebGL CORS error here.](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html)

If you want to test your code without getting this error you could run a local server

```
$ python3 -m http.server [port]
```

and you won't get a CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that the fromPixels() method is causing a CORS error but I'm unsure if thats certainly the case and anyways around it.

Yes that's correct, so you need use a relative path and don't use `file://`

And regarding the `<img>` element if look at the [documentation of `.fromPixels()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#fromPixels) you can see it allows multiple types of pixel formats:

> **pixels** (*ImageData|HTMLImageElement|HTMLCanvasElement|HTMLVideoElement*) The input image to construct the tensor from. The supported image types are all 4-channel.

One is `HTMLImageElement` so you can simply pass the `<img>`-element to `.fromPixels()`.

Comment: Even when doing that I am still being shown the same error. I pass in a `document.getElementById` corresponding to the ID of the image but the same CORS error is being shown.

Comment: Are you using relative paths or `file://`?

Comment: I'm using relative paths. Would that be cause for an issue?

Comment: CORS errors usually only come from cross-domain accesses like yoururl.com -> anotherurl.com or localhost -> file:// or file:// -> anotherurl.com.

Comment: Once again, same issue is showing up even though my tag is `<img src="file:///path_to_image"/> and my js/html file is local too.

Comment: file:// to file:// is always cross-origin

Comment: That is probably the issue then, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try adding the `crossorigin` attribute to your image element like `<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="" ...>`, or just host a local webserver

Comment: Did it work? If it doesn't I will write another answer

Comment: `Access to Image at 'file:///Users/anishkhanna/Documents/images/1.jpg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` is showing up now.

Comment: It seems file:// doesn't allow CORS at all, so just use a local webserver. Which IDE are you using, maybe it has one already.

Comment: I'm using brackets, I dont think it has it built in but if you recommend another IDE please do so.

Comment: It does have live preview which creates a webserver.

Comment: Works now! Thank you so much for the help!